# HttpWebRequest an Angular website

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code for getting a website and it works fine. The problem come up when I try to get a web page developed in Angular.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Timeout = 30000;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream flujo = response.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(flujo, encode);

String html;
try
   {
     html = readStream.ReadToEnd();
   } catch(System.IO.IOException)
   {
     return;
   }
response.Close();
readStream.Close();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument DOM = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
DOM.LoadHtml(html);
```

I know Angular first supply the skeleton of the page and in client side, fecth for info and display it.

When I try to get some info using HtmlAgilityPack, I get nothing.

My question is if it's possible to setup **HttpWebRequest** or **HttpWebResponse** or any other class to indicate to wait for javascript is done before getting the content or something similar.

Also, I tried to get content using WebBrowser and used the **loadCompleted** event and the same problem.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: For this you'd need to use something like PhantomJS and get the HTML after the JavaScript has been evaluated.